# SQL - Is there a way to hide a column from a select?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, join, subquery

i made a query that shows the result i want (close enough)... but it's not perfect as should be.

I'm counting the number of registers per user..

The SQL:

```
SELECT us.name, _reg FROM tb_user AS us
LEFT JOIN tb_register as rg ON rg.iduser = us.iduser
INNER JOIN
    (select rg.iduser, count(*)
        FROM tb_register AS rg    
        group by rg.iduser)
AS _reg ON rg.iduser = _reg.iduser

GROUP BY us.name, _reg
```

The result i get is something like...

```
+-----------+-----------------+
| name      | _reg            |
+-----------+-----------------+
| example_A | (id_A, count_A) |
+-----------+-----------------+
| example_B | (id_B, count_B) |
+-----------+-----------------+
```

But what i really want is just name and the row count..
I'm using in the subquery "rg.iduser" to reference in this INNER JOIN, but because of that, i get the "iduser" in the result.

**Is there a better way to do that to show what i want.. or a way to hide the "iduser" in the result of this query?**

Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gordon's answer shows you a better way to do the query. But I'd like to explain *why* you are seeing both columns in the output:

You are using the alias for the derived table `_reg` in the select list, which means you are retrieving every row from that derived table as an anonymous record. If you just want the count, then give that column a proper alias and reference the *column* in the outer select, not the *row*:

Also the `group by` in the outer select seems useless:

```
SELECT us.name, _reg.cnt  --<< HERE
FROM tb_user AS us
  LEFT JOIN tb_register as rg ON rg.iduser = us.iduser
  JOIN (
     select rg.iduser, count(*) as cnt --<< HERE
     FROM tb_register AS rg    
     group by rg.iduser
  ) AS _reg ON rg.iduser = _reg.iduser;
```

Answer (score 4):

Just select the column you want.  The query, though, is more simply written as:

```
SELECT us.name, COUNT(rg.iduser)
FROM tb_user us LEFT JOIN
     tb_register rg
     ON rg.iduser = us.iduser 
GROUP BY us.name;
```

Given what you want in the result set, there is no need for a subquery.

Note:  I am assuming that a given name is unique and does not span multiple `iduser`s.  Or, if it does, then you want the total count.  Based on your question and sample data, this seems reasonable.